# How to sort fields in _source for a search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a requirement where we are creating CSV from the search result of a particular query. The problem statement is:

There are certain questions with values stored in the elasticsearch. For example A with value of 1 or 0. B with Value of 1 and 0 and so on. Now when I retrieve the response, the questions(fields) in _search are not in order for example it comes as A,C,D,F,B. What we want is something to be added to query so that we have a sorted field list in_source such as A,B,C,D so that it can directly be mapped into CSV. Does elasticsearch provide any API of this sort?

Comment: If you are trying to order by fields (Key for which data is indexed ), I don't think you could do that, You cannot get json in any order. http://www.json.org/ . You can order based on key while writing to csv.

Comment: oki.. that makes sense.. just wanted to check if elasticsearch provides an option to this or not. Another question: Is there a way wherein I can make get a value in a variable and use it as a field in a single query?

Comment: Nope. I afraid that is even available later.

Answer (score 0):

Naively if you try to put

```
{
  ...
  "query": {...},
  "sort": [
    {
      "field_A": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
  ],
  ...
}
```

You will get an exception:

> No mapping found for [field_A] in order to sort on

Luckily Elasticsearch provides a mechanism to ignore fields those have no mapping and not sort by them:

```
{
  ...
  "query": {...},
  "sort": [
    {
      "field_A": {
        "order": "asc",
        "unmapped_type" : "long" // new here
      }
  ],
  ...
}
```

The value of this parameter is used to determine what sort values to emit.

Read more here [Ignoring Unmapped Fields | Elasticsearch Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/search-request-body.html#_ignoring_unmapped_fields)